# How do I query posts that don't have both of two tags?

Tags: wordpress

Say I have two tags, `red` and `small`. I want to get all posts that are not `red` *and* `small`. I want to include posts that are *either* `red` *or* `small`, but they can't be both.

The `tag__not_in` parameter won't work, because it'll exclude posts that are just `red` or just `small`.

I also tried the tax query below but then realized it's the same as the above.

```
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => 'red',
      'operator' => 'NOT IN',
    ),
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => 'small',
      'operator' => 'NOT IN',
    ),
  )
```

I feel like there's got to be a way to do this and I'm just missing something simple. That and I'm getting confused by the logic inversions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try again

```
<?php
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
          'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => 'red',
        ),
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
          'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => 'small',
        ),
    )
);

$query_red_small = new WP_Query( $args );
$post_ids = wp_list_pluck( $query_red_small->posts, 'ID' );

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post__not_in' => $post_ids
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @BinhNguyen. But if I'm not mistaken, isn't that the same as using the `tag__not_in` [parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#tag-parameters)? If so, then this will exclude a post that is just `red` or `small` (i.e. has only one of those tags). I want to exclude posts only if they are `red` _and_ `small` (i.e. they have both tags).

Comment: You can try the above code again, I just updated it